# angular 4 modal directive change size

Tags: angular

I am trying to change bs modal size dynamically via the class property as indicated in the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-_6K9Lz22wIVApzVCh2xHwBDEAAYASAAEgJFwvD_BwE#/modals#service-component), but cannot seem to get it to change size.

This is my html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imola-small-modal" bsModal #registrationModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" id="imola-small-modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title pull-left" i18n>{{PopupContent.PopupText}}</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="registrationModal.hide()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); false;">
                <div [dynamiccontent]="PopupContent.BodyRichtext"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="PopupContent.OnOkay(); registrationModal.hide();" i18n>{{PopupContent.OkaybuttonLabel}}</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="PopupContent.IsCloseButtonShown" (click)="registrationModal.hide();" i18n>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `appcomponent.ts`:

```
@ViewChild('registrationModal') public registrationModal: ModalDirective;

public ngOnInit(){
            this.registrationModal.config = new ModalOptions();
            this.registrationModal.config.class = 'modal-lg';
            this.registrationModal.show();

}
```

So the modal is showing, but is always small modal (as i hardcoded it in html). Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear about the model property (config.class) because this property is not used in your template html.

But I have one work around for your question.

You need to create one property for model size which is the class name and apply this class name on run time so you will get your expected output.

**Like –**

You need to change below line

**From**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

**To**

```
<div class="modal-dialog {{modelClass}}">
```

And in the .ts side you need to create public property

```
modelClass:string="modal-sm";
```

and change this property in the ngOnInit event.

```
public ngOnInit(){
   this.modelClass = "modal-lg";
```

Comment: fair enough, good idea, does not answer the question though, thus have not marked it as answered